# Place button on top of joining lines of two containers

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am new to the flutter world. For learning purposes, I am trying to create a dummy app and while doing so I came across a design and I am wondering how can I achieve this by making my design responsive across devices?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Column` with `Flexible` to set ratios between two `Container`(Blue and White in your example).

Put the button between containers and use `Transform.translate` to offset it for half it's height in a negative direction. This will put it on top of the `blue Conainer`.

#### Working example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(home: MyPage());
}

class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyPageState createState() => _MyPageState();
}

class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: _buildColumn(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildColumn() => Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          // First blue container
          _buildTopContainer(),
          // Button with offset
          _buildMidContainerWithButton(),
          // Bottom white container
          _buildBottomContainer(),
        ],
      );

  Widget _buildTopContainer() => Flexible(
        flex: 10,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.blue[900],
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Top container',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 17.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );

  Widget _buildMidContainerWithButton() {
    final buttonHeight = 50.0;
    return Stack(
      children: [
        // Use same background color like the second container
        Container(height: buttonHeight, color: Colors.white),
        // Translate the button 
        Transform.translate(
          offset: Offset(0.0, -buttonHeight / 2.0),
          child: Center(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () { /* do stuff */ },
              child: Container(
                height: buttonHeight,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.orange[400],
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(buttonHeight / 2.0),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      blurRadius: 16.0,
                      offset: Offset(0.0, 6.0),
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.16),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24.0, 3.0, 24.0, 0.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Icon(
                      Icons.photo_camera_outlined,
                      size: 20.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        'Use camera',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 17.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBottomContainer() => Flexible(
        flex: 5,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
            Text(
              'Bottom container',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 17.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                color: Colors.black54,
              ),
            ),
          ]),
        ),
      );
}
```

#### Result

[image]